# Even and Odd kinds

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, primes

Let \$n\$ be some positive integer. We say that \$n\$ is of *even kind* if the prime factorisation of \$n\$ (counting duplicates) has an even number of integers. For example, \$6  = 2 \times 3\$ is of even kind. Likewise, we say \$n\$ is of *odd kind* of the prime factorisation of \$n\$ has an odd number of integers, such as \$18 = 2 \times 3 \times 3\$. Note that as the prime factorisation of \$1\$ contains \$0\$ primes, it is of *even kind*.

Let \$E(n)\$ be the count of positive integers of even kind less than or equal to \$n\$, and \$O(n)\$ be the count of positive integers of odd kind less than or equal to \$n\$. For example, for \$n = 14\$, we have

- \$E(14) = 6\$ (\$1, 4, 6, 9, 10, 14\$), and
- \$O(14) = 8\$ (\$2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13\$)

---

You are to write a program which takes some positive integer \$n \ge 1\$ as input, and outputs the two values \$E(n)\$ and \$O(n)\$. You may input and output in any [convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447), and you may output the two outputs in any format that consistently presents the values (e.g. you cannot output one in unary and another in decimal), and that clearly distinguishes between the two (typically, has some kind of obvious delimiter).

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Test cases

```
n -> [E(n), O(n)]
1 -> [1, 0]
2 -> [1, 1]
3 -> [1, 2]
4 -> [2, 2]
5 -> [2, 3]
6 -> [3, 3]
7 -> [3, 4]
8 -> [3, 5]
9 -> [4, 5]
10 -> [5, 5]
11 -> [5, 6]
12 -> [5, 7]
13 -> [5, 8]
14 -> [6, 8]
15 -> [7, 8]
16 -> [8, 8]
17 -> [8, 9]
18 -> [8, 10]
19 -> [8, 11]
20 -> [8, 12]
```

Comment: Diamond coated brownie points for beating/matching my 7 byte Jelly answer

Comment: Trivia: [Polya conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_conjecture) states that E(n) <= O(n) for all n >= 2. This conjecture was proven to be false, with the smallest counterexample being n = 906,150,257.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Can we return only one value for `1`? The Japt answer does that but I don't feel like it's right (even though that would make things simpler for me)

Comment: @Fatalize No, you must return a `1` and a `0`. If, however, you are outputting only unary, then outputting an empty string is okay (as that's `0` in unary), but otherwise, there should be two clear values output.

Comment: Trivia on the trivia: Pólya never conjectured "Pólya's conjecture" (more accurately called "Pólya's problem")—instead he showed that it would imply the Riemann Hypothesis if it were true.

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
(-,])1#.2|1#@q:@+i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NXR1YjUNlfWMagyVHQqtHLQz9f5rcqUmZ@QrpCkYwhhGcBEDOMvkPwA)

- `1...+i.` 1 2 ... n
- `#@q:` Length `#` of prime factors `q:` of each
- `1#.2|` Sum of even lengths
- `(-,])` Input minus that sum `-` catted with `,` that sum `]`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
RÆE§ḂSṄạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//UsOGRcKn4biCU@G5hOG6of///zE0)

```
RÆE§ḂSṄạ
R         - Range [1, input]
 ÆE       - For each, get a list of the prime exponents
   §      - Sum each
    Ḃ     - Modulo each by 2
     S    - Sum
      Ṅ   - Print (with a trailing newline)
       ạ  - Get the absolute difference between this and the input (also implicitly printed)
```

Comment: Nice! You can still remove a byte tho :P

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 31 bytes

```
n->sum(i=1,n,I^(bigomega(i)%2))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboW-_N07YpLczUybQ118nQ84zSSMtPzc1PTEzUyNVWNNDUhqm6qpOUXaeQp2CoY6igYGegoFBRl5pUABZQUdO2ARJpGniZM7YIFEBoA)

Outputs a complex number where the real part is \$E(n)\$ and the imaginary part is \$O(n)\$.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,a=[0,0])=>n?f(n-1,a,a[(g=_=>k>n?0:n%k?g(k++):1^g(n/=k))(k=2)]++):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1BDoIwEEX3nGI2JjOhaMsSHDgIQTNBSrRkasC4MZ691t3Le/n5D3nLPm3356vSeJtT8oxqhAdr7Ejcae9RK2fEyIALX7kL2dlGD6FfMJQlNe6yoJ44EGHgmsa/k@TjhgoMrgWFM0NtM@QEnwJgirrHdT6uMU8N5AuitvimHw)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                 // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                  //   n = input
  a = [0, 0]          //   a[] = output array
) =>                  //
n ?                   // if n is not equal to 0:
  f(                  //   do a recursive call:
    n - 1,            //     decrement n
    a,                //     pass a[]
    a[                //     update a[]:
      ( g =           //       g is a recursive function
        _ =>          //       which ignores its parameter
        k > n ?       //       if k is greater than n:
          0           //         stop the recursion
        :             //       else:
          n % k ?     //         if k is not a divisor of n:
            g(k++)    //           increment k and do a recursive call
          :           //         else:
            1 ^       //           invert the result
            g(n /= k) //           divide n by k and do a recursive call
      )(k = 2)        //       initial call to g, starting with k = 2
    ]++               //     increment a[0] or a[1], depending on the
                      //     parity of the number of prime divisors of n
  )                   //   end of recursive call
:                     // else:
  a                   //   return a[]
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LÓOÉ1Ý¢
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/Bk/8OdhofnHlr0/7@hCQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9k4Opnr6TwqG2SgpK933@fw5P9D3caHp57aNF/nf8A).

**Explanation:**

-1 byte by realizing that: amount of prime factors of \$x\$ == sum(exponents of \$x\$'s prime factorization): [see that they are the same here](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fySezuMRKQcnex8X20DZ7Li4l14qC/LzUvJJihfw0hdTE5AyFssSc0lT1YoWCoszcVIW0xOSS/KLMqsSSzPw8kM7Dk225lIJLc2HqrRSAQMneXwdiXgCSrmIFjcy85JzSlMy8dIWU0oKczOTEktRiTbAWCACaNwlonk9qXnpJBsJIJftHTWvS7f//NzQBAA).

```python
L        # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 Ò       # Get the prime exponents of each inner integer
  O      # Sum each inner list together
   É     # Check for each sum whether it's odd
    1Ý   # Push pair [0,1]
      ¢  # Count the occurrences of 0 and 1 in the list
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Tounge-in-cheek, but since the question explicitly mentioned the possibility of unary output: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/Bk/8Od1f//G5oAAA) with unary output of zero-digits for E(n) and one-digits for O(n)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Nice bending of the rules. :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>101</s> 97 bytes

```
f(K)=∑_{k=1}^Kmod([1,0]+∑_{n=2}^klog_n(gcd(n^{ceil(log_nk)},k))sign(∏_{a=3}^nmod(n,a-1)),2)
```

Output is the list \$[E(n),O(n)]\$. It will fail on larger values due to floating point inaccuracies, but I've tested values such as \$1000\$ and it gives the right output, so it's pretty much a nonissue.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2yjtbj8wx9)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/stpjy9ydtp)

A shorter version of the above code technically works, but it fails for values greater than \$15\$ due to floating point errors (so it doesn't even pass all the test cases):

#### <s>88</s> 84 bytes

```
f(K)=∑_{k=1}^Kmod([1,0]+∑_{n=2}^klog_n(gcd(n^k,k))sign(∏_{a=3}^nmod(n,a-1)),2)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s5tgf5kpqk)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xdlkkemv0u)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 8 bytes

```
ɾǐvL∷∑…ε
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJvIiwiIiwiyb7HkHZM4oi34oiR4oCmzrUiLCIiLCIxNCJd)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>72</s> 66 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus)

```ruby
->n{[e=(1..n).map{|m|m.prime_division.sum{_2}}.count{_1%2<1},n-e]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnW0km5RQVFmbqpS7CI326WlJWm6FjeddO3yqqNTbTUM9fTyNPVyEwuqa3JrcvXACuNTMssyizPz8_SKS3Or441qa_WS80vzSqrjDVWNbAxrdfJ0U2NrISYtL1BwizY0iYXwFiyA0AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
'ǐ₂;L~ε"
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiJ8eQ4oKCO0x+zrVcIiIsIiIsIjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjZcbjdcbjhcbjlcbjEwXG4xMVxuMTJcbjEzXG4xNFxuMTVcbjE2XG4xN1xuMThcbjE5XG4yMCJd)

A flagless 8 byter that uses a method that is a little different to the other answer.

7 bytes using this approach with a flag:

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `o`, 7 bytes

```
'ǐ₂;L…ε
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBbyIsIiIsIifHkOKCgjtM4oCmzrUiLCIiLCIxXG4yXG4zXG40XG41XG42XG43XG44XG45XG4xMFxuMTFcbjEyXG4xM1xuMTRcbjE1XG4xNlxuMTdcbjE4XG4xOVxuMjAiXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, <s>58</s> 50 bytes

```factor
[ dup [1,b] [ factors length odd? ] count tuck - ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw7DsIwEET7nGIOABFQQkGJaGgQlZXCcdZJFP@w1wWnDyYW3WjmzdNSsY/r63l/3M6wkqc2SjdSqjnE2VJq9UbVDonemZwqyELRkUGIxPwpqGPMHmnKWhvCpWlOB4jjru9WgSGHmiHw1xlyYxH6Ybiig/K5CDirBXv8LqEqe4N2m23wiUBSTesX)

- `dup` Create an extra copy of the input.
- `[1,b]` Create a range from one to the input (inclusive).
- `[ ... ] count` Count the number of elements in the range for which `[ ... ]` returns true.
- `factors length odd?` Does it have an odd number of factors?
- `tuck -` Subtract the result from the input non-destructively. (Implicit multiple return)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Had to sacrifice 2 bytes to handle `1` :\

```
2Æõk è_Ê¤Ì¦X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Msb1ayDoX8qkzKZY&input=MjA)

```
2Æõk è_Ê¤Ì¦X     :Implicit input of integer U
2Æ               :Map each X in the range [0,2)
  õ              :  Range [1,U]
   k             :  Prime factors of each
     è           :  Count the elements that return true
      _          :  When passed through the following function
       Ê         :    Length
        ¤        :    To binary string
         Ì       :    Last character
          ¦X     :    Not equal to X?
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 40 bytes

```
Length/@PrimeOmega@Range@#~GroupBy~OddQ&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/a67e802b-076e-4cde-b16f-0bd0863a2f0a)

Output in the form `<|False->E(n),True->O(n)|>`.

Comment: For n=1, outputs just `<|False->1|>`.

Comment: As noted by Bubbler, the output format doesn't work for `n = 1`, as it should include both `E(n)` and `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 79 bytes

```
\(n)c(y<-sum(sapply(1:n,f<-\(n,p=2)sum(x<-!n%%p,if(n>1)f(n/p^x,p+!x))%%2)),n-y)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGa_JSU1LLUvOzMvBTbpaUlaboWN_1jNPI0kzUqbXSLS3M1ihMLCnIqNQyt8nTSbHSBUjoFtkaaIJkKG13FPFXVAp3MNI08O0NNIKlfEFehU6CtWKGpqapqpKmpk6dbqQkxdgfcICMDHSRbodILFkBoAA)

Returns O(n), E(n).

Helper function `f` returns the number of prime factors, `f%%2` returns whether-or-not this is odd:  `f<-\(n,p=2)sum(x<-!n%%p,if(n>1)f(n/p^x,p+!x))`

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 63 bytes

```
.+
$*
M!&`.+
+%`^(2*(1+))\2+$
2$1
22|¶

O`2?1
(1)+(21)*
$#1 $#2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@nzaWixeWrqJYAZPkncKlq@CYYoopqqybEaRhpaRhqa2rGGGmrcBmpGHIZGdUc2sYF1GFkb8ilYaiprWFkqKnFpaJsqKCibPT/v5EBAA) Link is to test suite that outputs the results for `1..n`. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
M!&`.+
```

List all the numbers from `n` down to `1`.

```
+%`^(2*(1+))\2+$
2$1
```

Count the number of prime factors of each number, using repeated `2`s as the count. This leaves a lone trailing `1` once all of the prime factors have been counted.

```
22|¶
```

Take the parity of the counts of prime factors, so that `1` means that it had an even number and `21` means that it had an odd number, and join all of the results together.

```
O`2?1
```

Sort the `1`s and `21`s separately to make them easier to count.

```
(1)+(21)*
$#1 $#2
```

Count the number of `1`s and `21`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator), 66 bytes

```
InputBox(n
a=Sum(Zip(Mod(Length(PrimeFactors(a)),2),a,1...n
ai+n-a
```

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/zfv6h837)

Output is in the form \$E(n)+O(n)i\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.1], 92 bytes

```julia
using Primes
~N=(X=map(n->sum([b for (a,b)=factor(n)]),1:N);[sum(X.%2 .==0),sum(isodd.(X))])
```

Julia 1.0 [appears to be supported by the package Primes.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Primes.jl/blob/fde566c12c3c1d5418d6d2e67087ed9cb2a11db0/Project.toml#L18), but I haven't been able to import it successfully. Here is the output in Julia 1.1:

```julia
julia> VERSION
v"1.1.1"

julia> using Primes

julia> ~N=(X=map(n->sum([b for (a,b)=factor(n)]),1:N);[sum(X.%2 .==0),sum(isodd.(X))])
~ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> map(x -> println(lpad(x,2) * " -> $(~x)"), 1:20);
 1 -> [1, 0]
 2 -> [1, 1]
 3 -> [1, 2]
 4 -> [2, 2]
 5 -> [2, 3]
 6 -> [3, 3]
 7 -> [3, 4]
 8 -> [3, 5]
 9 -> [4, 5]
10 -> [5, 5]
11 -> [5, 6]
12 -> [5, 7]
13 -> [5, 8]
14 -> [6, 8]
15 -> [7, 8]
16 -> [8, 8]
17 -> [8, 9]
18 -> [8, 10]
19 -> [8, 11]
20 -> [8, 12]
```

This solution could be adapted without `Primes` in Julia 0.4, when `factor` was still part of base Julia.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
aBsm.&1lPh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9GpOFdPzTAnAMg2tAAA)

Outputs `[O(n), E(n)]`.

#### Explanation

```
aB            bifurcate the absolute difference of implicit eval(input()) and
  s           the sum of
   m          map over implicit range(eval(input()))
    .&1       modulo 2 (bitwise and 1)
       l      the length of 
        P     the list of the prime factors of
         h    1 + implicit map lambda variable
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
⟦₁{ḋl%₂}ᵍlᵐĊ|;0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9icmFjaHlsb2cy///in6bigoF74biLbCXigoJ94bWNbOG1kMSKfDsw//8yMP9a)

#### Explanation

4 additional bytes needed at the end to deal with the special case of `1`.

```
⟦₁                  Range [1, ..., Input]
  {    }ᵍ           Group by:
   ḋl%₂                 Length of prime decomposition mod 2
         lᵐ         Map length
            Ċ|;0    Output must have 2 elements; otherwise (Input = 1), Output = [Input, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
Ｆ…·¹Ｎ«≔⁰θＷΦι¬﹪ι⁺²λ«≧÷⁺²⌊κι≦¬θ»⊞υθ»ＩＥ²№υι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoIwEETP8BU9bpOaiPHmyWhMOEAIf1ChwsbSIu3iwfDttQQT9zabmTfT9HJqrNQhPOzEIDeNJoezqqXpFGSC5WYkX9JwVxNwztknTc7OYWdgL9iLn9Lk3aNWDG6offSgYKX1UNiWtF1VFYFwEExz/ssnhRw3Ro1d72Opv@KMrfqbCzQ40ABPzgXDteUfgsj/VS9pUpHrgTa9pNWExsNFurhAjivpYil@aKXEO4WQHcNu1l8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ…·¹Ｎ«
```

Loop from `1` up to and including `n`.

```
≔⁰θ
```

Assume even kind.

```
ＷΦι¬﹪ι⁺²λ«
```

While the current value has any nontrivial factors: ...

```
≧÷⁺²⌊κι
```

... divide it by the lowest such factor, and...

```
≦¬θ
```

... flip between even and odd kind.

```
»⊞υθ
```

Save the kindness of the current value.

```
»ＩＥ²№υι
```

Output the counts of even and odd kindness.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 11 bytes

```
@€olé;ΣD³a«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/3@FR05r8nMMrrc8tdjm0OfHQ6v//jQwA)

Returns a list of `[E(n), O(n)]`. Note that Ohm v2 formats numbers a little weirdly when they are in a list, but they are definitely the right numbers.

### Explained

```
@€olé;ΣD³a«
@            # Push a range from 1 to the input to the stack
 €   ;       # To each item in the range from before:
  ol         # Get the length of the full prime factorization of the item
    é        # and then push whether the length is even
      ΣD     # Push two copies of the sum of that list - the first copy is how many numbers are E(n), and the second will be used to calculate how many numbers are O(n)
        ³a   # Get the absolute difference of the input and the E(n) count
          «  # Pair into a list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 52 bytes

```arturo
$[n][x:∑map 1..n=>[%size factors.prime&2]@[n-x,x]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?6Z5NSY)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 13 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 10.70 bytes

```
R1+Zh.S2%10dc
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrgwy1ozL0go1UDQ1SkiFiUKkFiwxNICwA) Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

#### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 16 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 13.17 bytes

```
DR1+Zh.S2%SDZKAD
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYbXIIMtaMy9IKNVINdorwdXSDCUNkFiwxNICwA) Port of Steffan's Jelly answer.

##### Explanations

```python
R1+Zh.S2%10dc  # Implicit input
R1+            # Push range(1, input + 1)
   Zh          # Prime factor exponents
     .S2%      # Sum mod 2 of each
         10dc  # Count 1s and 0s
```

```python
DR1+Zh.S2%SDZKAD  # Implicit input
DR1+              # Duplicate and push range(1, input + 1)
    Zh            # Prime factor exponents
      .S2%        # Sum mod 2 of each
          SDZK    # Sum and print without popping
              AD  # Absolute difference with input
```